# Cant Enable PDO features from whm panel

Tags: php, cpanel, whm, servermanager

I have dedicated server and installed WHM and cPanel as well on server but I can access PDO features. It gives message like

> **Fatal error:** Class 'PDO' not found in /home...

I checked from WHM panel > Easyapache 3. all PDO check boxes are checked there.

Please help me if you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run **phpinfo()** in a quick script and *double check* if **PDO** is in fact enabled.

If you have ssh access to your web-server or an option to directly edit the php.ini file in some manner add the following:

```
extension="pdo.so"
extension="pdo_mysql.so"
```

If you don't have that capability with your hosting provider, you may need to contact them and ask for the extensions to be added on their side.